# How to renew a code signing certificate

Tags: certificate, signtool

I have a code signing certificate from Thawte that is about to expire in a couple of weeks.

I have paid for a renewal, and i have received a renewal .cer file.

I have successfully created an updated .pfx file that allows me to sign Firefox addons, and the signature is valied in "future" time.

However, when i try to use the same .pfx file to sign an Internet Explorer plug-in, i get a signtool error 0x80880253 ("the certificate is no longer valid").

I try to use mmc.exe and certmgr.exe to renew the certificate in my certificate manager console,
but whatever i do - the expiration date remains in 2010.

I was able to see the "renewed" certificate in the certmgr wizard, but it was under the "other people" tab rather than under the "personal" tab.

does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have your new certificate in Personal store. Try to delete it and install again.

If you are not successfull, you may try a workaround of referencing directly to .pfx file instead of the certificate storage:

`signtool.exe sign /f certificate.pfx /p MYPASSWORD ....`